# What does "16 -> 14 AWG" mean?

Tags: connector, terminology

I'm looking at [this product](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/crimp-tab-terminals/7978868/?searchTerm=797-8868), contacts for a connector.

[image: Screenshot of website]

The text says:

> Molex 19420 Series PCB Connector Contact, 2.55 x 2.8 mm, 16 → 14 AWG Tin Plated

What does the last part mean?

> 16 → 14 AWG

Answer (score 14, accepted):

16 -> 14 AWG is simply stating that the connector contact recepticle (where the wire is crimped to the contact) can accept wire diameters in this range, [see also](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge).

Note that a higher AWG size value means a smaller diameter.

Comment: Makes sense. A bit strange that they use an arrow to imply a range, and that they write the greatest number first.

Comment: @MadsSkjern From 16 (the smallest gauge) to 14 (the largest gauge). :-)

Comment: American Wire Gauge - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge

Comment: Ouf, that explains :)

Comment: Any two successive gauges (e.g. A & B ) have diameters in the ratio (dia. B ÷ dia. A) of \$ \sqrt [39]{92} \$. Easy, isn't it? _[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge)_.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the arrow means "16 through 14" - just another way of saying "from 16 (included) to 14 (included)".